# Expect call shell script

Tags: bash, expect

I am trying to call a shell script and store the result in an expect variable. get_pw.sh accepts 2 args and decrypts the file using the provided md5hash. If I execute ./get_pw.sh file.test md5hash from the bash prompt it returns the password string as expected. When called from expect, the password does not get returned. The expect debug shows:

```
expect: does "" (spawn_id exp0) match regular expression "[^\s]"?
```

So it looks like the script is not returning the password string when called from expect. Relevant code:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
send "./get_pw.sh file.test md5hash \r"
expect -re {[^\s]} {
set password $expect_out(0,string)
}
puts "The password is: $password"
```

Comment: What are you sending that command string to? Does `get_pw.sh` output to standard output or standard error or the tty directly?

Comment: get_pw.sh is outputting to standard output. Expect debug shows this when sending the command



    `send: sending "./get_pw.sh file.test md5hash \r" to exp0 ./get_pw.sh file.test md5hash`

Comment: Are you automating a shell here that is supposed to be running that command or are you trying to run `get_pw.sh` as a local command (through a local shell)? If the latter then see Jens' answer.

Comment: Does that script require any manual interaction? If not, accept Jens' answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `spawn` a command first before you can `send` input and `expect` output from it.

To set an *expect* variable to the output of a command, use

```
set varname [exec command]
```

Comment: Okay - think I am getting further. I `spawn /bin/bash` and was at least able to see the output - however `set password [./get_pw.sh file.test md5hash];` gave me an invalid command name error when executing the script

Comment: @Polyamorous You need to read my example carefully: there's an `exec` missing.

Comment: @Polyamorous Just for completeness, using the `[exec ...]` syntax is like using the shell's backticks or `varname=$(./get_pw.sh file.test md5hash)`. You do not need to spawn a shell for this. Expect forks the process and assigns the output to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you must do this with expect,

```
  log_user 0
  spawn -noecho get_pw.sh file hash
  expect eof
  set passwd [string trimright $expect_out(buffer) "\r\n"]
  puts $passwd
```

Jens's answer looks pretty good by now ...